# Alterar tamanho da área do plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Gerei um scatter plot, mas não consigo alterar o tamanho da tela em que ele aparece no meu notebook. Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

```
plt.scatter(X,Y,label='Y(X)'); # sacater plot
plt.xlabel('X');
plt.ylabel('Y');
plt.legend();
```

Tentei usar o parâmetro `plt.scatter(X,Y,label='Y(X)',figsize=(x,y)` mas não funcionou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para começar, o seu código não vai rodar em lugar algum.

**Por que?**

Porque possui inúmeros erros - não importou a biblioteca, não listou os pontos, etc.

Diante desses problemas, resolvi implementar um exemplo prático de gráfico `scatter` utilizando a biblioteca `matplotlib`, para ficar à sua disposição, bem como, à disposição de todo e qualquer usuário da plataforma que, porventura, venha precisar.

**Observação**

Gráficos do tipo [Scatter](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_custom_symbol.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-custom-symbol-py), são gráficos que exibem pontos. Este pontos são intersecções entre linhas `verticais` e `horizontais` - idêntico ao [Plano Cartesiano](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/o-que-e/matematica/o-que-e-plano-cartesiano.htm).

**Exemplo**

Elabore um gráfico do tipo scatter que possui `5` pontos com o auxílio da biblioteca matplotlib.

Para resolver este exemplo podemos utilizar o seguinte script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

titulo = input('Digite o título do gráfico: ')
legenda = input('Digite a legenda do gráfico: ')

n = int(input('Desejas inserir quantos pontos? '))

x = list()
y = list()
for c in range(1, n + 1):
    pontos = list(map(int, input(f'Digite as coordenadas do {c}º ponto: ').split()))
    x.append(pontos[0])
    y.append(pontos[1])

fp = input('Digite a forma dos pontos: ')
tp = int(input('Digite o tamanho dos pontos: '))

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.scatter(x, y, label=f'{legenda}', color='k', s=tp, marker=f'{fp}')
plt.xlabel('eixo X', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('eixo y', fontsize=15)
plt.title(f'{titulo}\n', fontsize=20)
plt.legend(fontsize=10)

plt.show()
```

Observe que quando executamos o script recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite o título do gráfico:`. Neste momento devemos digitar o título `Intersecções de pontos` e pressionar `enter`. Depois recebemos a segunda mensagem: `Digite a legenda do gráfico:` . Neste momento devemos digitar a legenda `Pontos` e pressionar `enter`.

Como este script é mais generalista, o mesmo nos solicitará a quantidade de pontos e, neste momento devemos digitar `5` e pressionar `enter`. Em seguida receberemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite as coordenadas do 1º ponto:` . Neste momento devemos digitar as **duas** coordenadas do ponto (x, y), na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `enter`. Em seguida devemos repetir as operações para os outros `4` pontos. Posteriormente, recebermos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite a forma dos pontos:` . Neste momento devemos pressionar uma tecla da qual queremos utilizar o carácter correspondente para exibir o ponto - pressionando o `X`, o ponto será exibido como um xis. Posteriormente receberemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite o tamanho dos pontos:` . Neste momento devemos digitar `40` e pressionar `enter`.

Depois de termos alimentado todas as variáveis do gráfico o matplotlib irá processar os dados e, em seguida, exibirá o mesmo.

**Observações**

**1.** O processamento do gráfico demorará alguns segundos, de acordo com o hardware de sua máquina;

**2.** A linha de comando do código, que de fato, irá **controlar** o tamanho da tela que exibe o gráfico é:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
```

O valor **10** corresponde à `largura` e o valor **6** corresponde à `altura`. Se quiseres mudar estas dimensões, basta alterar os valores numéricos.

Comment: Muito boa explicação!!! Obrigado!

Agora se eu quiser alterar o tamanho da legenda dentro do scatterplot é possível? Não estou encontrando os parâmetros na documentação


`plt.figure(figsize=(9,7)) # definindo tamanho do gráfico
plt.scatter(X,Y,label='Y(X)'); # como alterar o tamanho dessa legenda dentro o gráfico?
plt.xlabel('Eixo X'); # legenda do eixo X
plt.ylabel('Eixo Y'); # legenda do eixo 
plt.legend();
plt.show();`

Comment: @LpCoutinho, Se a resposta resolveu seu problema, podes `aceitá-la`, clicando em `V` ao lado da resposta. [Veja aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta) porque aceitar. Apesar de não ser obrigatório, esta prática é estimulada no site, indicando a futuros visitantes que tal resposta resolveu o problema. E quando tiveres 15 pontos, [também poderás votar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em quaisquer respostas que jugares úteis.

Comment: @LpCoutinho, para alterar o tamanho da legenda basta alterar o valor do `fontsize` na linha `plt.legend(fontsize=10)`. Você pode altera para 20, 30, 40, ou 5, 8, etc.

Comment: @LpCoutinho, se você quiser alterar o tamanho do `fontsize` dos label  `plt.xlabel('eixo X', fontsize=15)` e `plt.ylabel('eixo y', fontsize=15)`, basta também alterar os valores numéricos para o que você quiser.

Comment: @Solkarped, em `label=f'{legenda}'` pode-se fazer direto `label=legenda` a mesma coisa no `marker=f'{fp}'`. Não existe a necessidade dessa formatação. Abraço!

Comment: @LpCoutinho, `legenda` é uma coisa e `label` é outra. A Legenda, geralmente, está dentro da área útil do gráfico. Os label se encontram fora. O  label `Eixo X` se encontra abaixo do eixo dos "X" e label `Eixo Y` se encontra na lateral do eixo dos "Y". Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Criando dados dummy:

```
X = np.arange(1,20)
Y = X * np.random.randint(19, 40, 19)
```

Aqui é a linha que faz o trabalho de mudar o tamanho do plot:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
```

Restante do seu código:

> ```
> plt.scatter(X,Y,label='Y(X)')
> plt.xlabel('X')
> plt.ylabel('Y')
> plt.legend()
> ```

Mostra o plot:

```
plt.show()
```

---

Edit

Para adicionar o tamanho da fonte basta utilizar `fontsize` dentro de `xlabel`, `ylabel` e `legend`

```
plt.xlabel('X', fontsize = 18)
plt.ylabel('Y', fontsize = 18)
plt.legend(fontsize = 20)
```

Comment: Genial, atendeu o problema rápido!!!

Agora se eu quiser alterar o tamanho da legenda dentro do scatterplot é possível? Não estou encontrando os parâmetros na documentação


`plt.figure(figsize=(9,7)) # definindo tamanho do gráfico
plt.scatter(X,Y,label='Y(X)'); # como alterar o tamanho dessa legenda dentro o gráfico?
plt.xlabel('Eixo X'); # legenda do eixo X
plt.ylabel('Eixo Y'); # legenda do eixo 
plt.legend();
plt.show();`

Comment: Estamos ai meu caro! Abraço!

Comment: Adicionei a resposta seu novo questionamento. Abraço!

Comment: Muito bom! Você é Fera, mas eu quero alterar a fonte da legenda que fica dentro do plot, em: `plt.scatter(X,Y,label='Y(X)');`

Comment: A ideia é a mesma: `plt.legend(fontsize = 20)`